# Junit <junitreport> tag generates invalid HTML files for Selenium tests

Tags: html, ant, selenium, junit, report

I am using ANT to generate Selenium HTML reports, and publish them in Jenkins with the Selenium HTML Report plugin. The report plugin gives IO exception due elements not being closed in the HTML files.

I look at the generated HTML files and this is what I found:

```
<html xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:stringutils="xalan://org.apache.tools.ant.util.StringUtils">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Unit Test Results: All Tests</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Style" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
...
</html>
```

Looking at the element structure, the Jenkins plugin gives the exception for  tags? What is happening here? It is like the outputted HTML files are invalid.

I am using the  tag to generate the files like this:

```
<junitreport todir="${dir}">
        <fileset dir="${dir}">
            <include name="*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${dir}/html" />
</junitreport>
```

Comment: Does the outputted html itself contain (malformed) html?

Comment: If the HTML file is opened in a browser, I think it renders fine. At least I can't see any glitches.

Answer (score 0):

i also had same problem but with Junit and Jenkins report publishing feature.

after a quick search i found a plugin "HTML Publisher Plugin" .
After i installed this plugin in jenkins , i had to modify "post-build Actions" section of my job, and the problem solved!.

Hope it helps you !